# Customize table header

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, itext

I'm using iText 5.5.2

I have defined a table for a mobile phone invoice like this:

- First row: *Data for MSISDN: 777 888 999*
- Second row: *Time / Duration / Cost*
- Third, fourth...: *12:29 / 35s / 0.32*

I have set the first and second rows as the table headers, and that works perfectly.

Now, I want to introduce a detail like this (when table takes more than one page):

- First row, the first page: *Data for MSISDN: 777 888 999*
- First row, from the second page and so on: *Data for MSISDN: 777 888 999 **(next)***

Any idea to insert that word *next* from the second page in the table?

Comment: I would look into [`PdfPTableEventSplit`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17497215/231316) but I don't know if you'll be able to modify the table itself. See [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23435210/231316) (C# but pretty much the same as Java) for putting a "Showing rows XXX through YYY" that you might be able to adapt

Comment: @chris-haas , thanks. I'll take a look at this and give it a try.